# Iptables block ping from another ip

Tags: networking, server, dns, iptables, firewall

I am a beginner in the field could you help me please

me : `192.168.15.13`

user1 : `192.168.15.14`

user2 : `192.168.15.12`

I would like to block ping from user1 to user2 using iptables from my ip `192.168.15.13`.

So I made this: `iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p icmp -s 192.168.15.14 -d 192.168.15.12 -j DROP`

But it doesn't work, in fact I don't even know if it's really possible to block ping from another ip.

thank you for helping me

Comment: I am sure, there are more qualified people to answer this question, but why don't you block ping in iptables on user 2 (192.168.15.12)? Maybe it would help to know what devices these actually are and why you need it to be "unpingable"?

Comment: It's unclear why each user has a different IP address. That's not generally how Ubuntu works. Perhaps there is an element to the question that is missing? Or is each user on a different machine?

Comment: yes its a different machine

Comment: What you are attempting to do is not possible.